# Expected performance with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

The getstream.io documentation says that one should expect retrieving a feed in approximately 60ms. When I retrieve my feeds they contain a field named 'duration' which I take is the calculated server side processing time. This value is steadily around 10-40ms, with an average around 15ms.

The problem is, I seldomly get my feeds in less than 150ms and the average time is rather around 200-250ms and sometimes up to 300-400ms. This is the time for the getting the feed alone, no enrichment etc., and I have verified with tcpdump that the network roundtrip is low (around 25ms), and that the time is actually spent waiting for the server to respond.

I've tried to move around my application (eu-west and eu-central) but that doesn't seem to affect things much (again, network roundtrip is steadily around 25ms).

My question is - should I really expect 60ms and continue investigating, or is 200-400ms normal? On the getstream.io site it is explained that developer accounts receive "Low Priority Processing" - what does this mean in practise? How much difference could I expect with another plan?

I'm using the node js low level API.

Comment: can you share the API request that you are testing?

Comment: Of course! https://gist.github.com/averas/01c00259465a6f66d1212dd3d4617c57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream APIs use SSL to encrypt traffic. Unfortunately SSL introduces additional network I/O. Usually you need to pay for the increased latency only once because Stream HTTP APIs supports [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) (aka keep-alive).

Here's a Wireshark screenshot of the TCP traffic of 2 sequential API requests with keep alive disabled client side:

[image: pcap no keep-alive]

The 4 lines in red highlight that the TCP connection is getting closed each time. Another interesting thing is that the handshaking takes almost 100ms and it's done twice (the first bunch of lines).

After some investigation, it turns out that the library used to make API requests to Stream's APIs (request) does not have keep-alive enabled by default. Such change will be part of the library soon and is available on a [development branch](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js/tree/keep-alive).

Here's a screenshot of the same two requests with keep-alive enabled (using the code from that branch):

[image]

This time there is not connection reset anymore and the second HTTP request does not do SSL handshaking.

Comment: Awesome! I tried the development branch and now I am retrieving feeds at 120ms on average from my server, with 25-40ms of that probably attributed to "normal" network latency.  Have you looked at some of the ways to decrease SSL latency except from the keep-alive you fixed? Such as false start and resumption (https://istlsfastyet.com/)? I imagine many of your clients being "returning clients" (as long as we're talking backend servers) meaning such approaches could be quite beneficial.